# WCF Web API - Model Binding to an object (Ensure that a request HttpOperationHandler has an output parameter with a type assignable to...)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf-web-api

On WCF Web API Preview 5, I am dealing with a strange behavior. Here is the scenario:

This is my model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

This is the API:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class PersonApi {

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "person?id={ID}&name={Name}&surname={Surname}&age={Age}")]
    public Person Get(Person person) {

        return person;
    }

}
```

I registered the API with the following code:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<ADummy.PersonApi>("Dummy");
```

When I run try to reach the service with following URL, I get this error:

> localhost:36973/Dummy/person?id=1&name=Tugberk&surname=Ugurlu&age=24

---

> The service operation 'Get' will never receive a value for the input
>   parameter 'person' of type 'Person'. Ensure that a request
>   HttpOperationHandler has an output parameter with a type assignable to
>   'Person'.

But when I change my API logic like below it works:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class PersonApi {

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "person?id={ID}&name={Name}&surname={Surname}&age={Age}")]
    public Person Get(int ID, string Name, string Surname, int Age) {

        var p = new Person { 
            ID = ID,
            Name = Name,
            Surname = Surname,
            Age = Age
        };

        return p;
    }

}
```

In WCF Web API, I suppose things are not working like they work in ASP.NET MVC.

What is way of model binding to an object in WCF Web API?

**UPDATE**

I have added another method:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate= "put", Method="POST")]
public Person Put(Person person) {

    return person;
}
```

When I call this method with the following details:

> Method: POST
>
> URL: http://localhost:36973/Dummy/put
>
> Accept:*/* Content-Type:text/xml
>
> Content-Length:189
>
> BODY:
>
> ```
> <Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
> <ID>1</ID>
> <Name>Tugberk</Name>
> <Surname>Ugurlu</Surname>
> <Age>25</Age>
> </Person>
> ```

I get what I needed. So, query string binding to custom objects is not allowed?

Comment: Will the Person model be bound correctly if you change your action from Get() to Post()?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your experience, it appears that the design behavior is that Get() actions will only bind the parameters defined in your UriTemplate.  In terms of purpose and security, this is the correct behavior.

Comment: but the post didn't bind the query strings, too?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is unclear.  Did you try a POST where you passed your defined query string?  If so, what was the result?

Comment: I tried and get the same error. if I post with structured xml of json format, it binds the input to an object. You seem not to have a decent knowledge about the issue as I do. so, we both guess based on our guts here.

Answer (score 0):

With latest version of [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) (released with ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta) model binding is supported.

*Model binding and validation: Model binders provide an easy way to extract data from various parts of an HTTP request and convert those message parts into .NET objects which can be used by the Web API actions.*

With previous versions of ASP.NET Web API the desired functionality can be implemented with a HttpOperationHandler and in the OnHandle method return the model. Maybe the [Validating model properties WCF Web APi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974205/validating-model-properties-wcf-web-api) question and answers can be used for inspiration.